# WoW - Target Scan Enemy macro

Tags: world-of-warcraft

WoW added a keybinding called **Target Scan Enemy (Hold)** which works wonders in targeting the mobs in the center of the screen.

Is there a command that would trigger the same functionality (i.e. one I could use in a macro)?

Answer (score 4):

According to [the forums](http://us.battle.net/forums/en/wow/topic/20747796188) someone has posted that

> Target Scan Enemy can't be used in a macro, unfortunately.
> The reason is this new binding does two actions: on key down it begins the "scan" and on key up it does the actual targeting.
>
> A macro can't participate in both the key down and key up event. When macros run they process each line and then leave in one pass. You may not know this but your client is actually locked up while it's running the macro. It's just so fast you can never notice it.
>
> If they ever add a binding attribute to secure buttons, it would be possible to do an instant scan/target with this binding. But you can do that already with

- /cleartarget
- /targetenemy

> in a macro
>
> /cleartarget resets the "next target" back to start and /targetenemy (should) pick a target in front of you.

So, technically just put them 2 things in a macro and it should do the same thing!

Comment: The problem with this is it targets things not exactly in front of you if there's nothing in front of you. With spammy macros this tends to end up in unintentional pulls :(

Comment: My apologies, I shall try to find some other things online and try in game a little myself

Comment: I don't know my way around WoW, but wouldn't it be possible to check if the enemy is already aggresive? That way you could make sure there are no unintentional pulls. Downside of course being that you can't start a fight with that macro.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray I don't have WoW open right now, but maybe something like `/targetenemy [combat]`?